# Is it possible to play HTML5 video in opposite direction or bidirectional? it does not contain any audio

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, jwplayer, flowplayer, video.js

Is it possible to play HTML5 video in opposite direction or bidirectional? 
it does not contain any audio. Please suggest if you also aware of any plugin

Comment: Interesting, I have not heard of any plugin for this, I'm afraid.